# How much do the hyperparameters matter to a Gaussian Process?

Tags: gaussian-process, rbf-kernel

While a Gaussian Process is completely defined by its *mean* and *covariance* functions, how much do the **hyperparameters** of the *covariance* function matter to the GP?

Take the *RBF* *covariance* function for instance:

$k(x,x') = σ^2exp({-(x-x')^2}/{2l^2})$

I only roughly understand that the *σ<sup>2</sup>* controls the **magnitude** of the *covariance*, thus the deviation from the *mean* of the GP. And the *lengthscale* *l* controls the decay of the *covariance*. But is there a direct or measurable relationship between these **hyperparameters** and the shape (e.g. variation) of the GP?

With a more concrete example, here, I have two groups of sample realizations of two GPs, one group of the samples are from GP with fixed **hyperparameters**, say *σ<sup>2</sup>=4.5* and *l=2* (upper image), while another group of samples are from another GP with *σ<sup>2</sup>=9* and *l=2* (lower image):

[image]
[image]

How do the patterns of the samples in the two image reflect the fact that the *σ<sup>2</sup>* has been doubled with *l=2* unchanged?

Would anyone please give me some hints?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The covariance function parameters matter a lot, because they specify the distribution over functions. As your plots show, the sampled functions have similar shapes in both cases but the amplitudes are larger when you increase $\sigma^2$. Try changing the length scale and you'll see something very different.

Comment: @user20160 Thanks, totally agree. But is there a measurable quantity directly linked to the increase of the amplitudes? For instance, doubled kernel variance ***σ*** means a doubled amplitudes, or doubled deviation from the mean?

Comment: When you sample from a GP, the function values (at a given set of points) are drawn from a Gaussian distribution, whose covariance matrix is determined by the covariance function. In your case, $\sigma^2$ scales the entire covariance matrix. So, if you double $\sigma^2$, you'll double the variance of the function value each point. You'll also double the covariance between function values at each pair of points.